# WPF UserControl throws NullReferenceException when loading

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a WPF project with a main `Window` and a `UserControl`.

In the `Usercontrol` I set a `GridControl.ItemsSource` using `gridcontrol.ItemsSource = query.tolist()`, but when loading the `Usercontrol` it throws an `Exception`:

> "The object reference not set to an object"

In spite of the query returning 40 rows of data.

The code is executed in the MainWindow but the `UserControl` throws the exception.

Comment: Have you tried break pointing or try/catching to see where it is throwing the error?

Comment: ye dear friend i did it alot the error throw when i cal usercontrol.but if i remove gridcontrol.itemsource = query.tolist() it does'nt have any problem and usercotrol load with empty gridcontrol

Comment: When you step through in break mode, can you test each value and see if any are null? Both gridcontrol and query.

Comment: If you break point at that line (presuming you're using something like visual studio) are either the `GridControl` or `query` null? Is the call to `InitializeComponent()` being made before this line?

Comment: yes the erro happen on this line of code when i call usercontrol:
 panel2 = DockLayoutManager_M.DockController.AddDocumentPanel(DocumentGroup_M,
                new Uri(@"Test1;component\UserControl2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));but if i remove gridcontrol source setting code from usercontrol.it works

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` will mean that either the `GridControl` or `query` is null. Is this line after any `InitializeComponent()` call?

Comment: i change my code alittel
now i have the error on this line of code:
gridcontrol.itemsource = query.tolist();
the query is not null but when i keep mouse in gridcontrol writes this.gridcontrol null

Comment: This will mean that `gridcontrol` hasn't been initialised . In the constructor for the `UserControl` you should have a call to `InitializeComponent()` is this before or after the line that throws the error?

Comment: i had my cod in pubic personnel (){} and the initializecomponent was in private Personnel(){}.now i add an initializecomponent befor my cod
and i recieved another error:
no default constructor found for usercontrol.this error happen on the line i call usercontrol.what can i do

Comment: Are you able to post the code for your constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating the conversation from the comments on the question:

A `NullReferenceException` is thrown on the line

```
gridcontrol.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

as `gridcontrol` is null.

For more information on this `Exception` see [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?rq=1)

I'm guessing that the line in question is before the call to `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor.

This method initialises all of the controls in the `UserControl`. Therefore, if trying to use a `Control` before a call to this method, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

What you will want to see is:

```
public YourUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gridcontrol.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks alot
i do that and now my gridcontrol works.i have a collection view source it has the same error collectionviewsource is null and i set it after initialize method the code is : collectionviewsource.source = an observablecollection()

Comment: ObservableCollection<Personnel> _Personnel = new ObservableCollection<Personnel>();
CollectionViewSource PersonCollection = new CollectionViewSource();       
DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.DockLayoutManager dockmanager;
public UC_Personnel(DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.DockLayoutManager _dockManager){
  InitializeComponent();
  PersonCollection = (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["MyResource"];           
            this.dockmanager = _dockManager;
            this._Personnel = new ObservableCollection<Personnel>(context.Personnels);
            PersonCollection.Source = this._Personnel;      
        }

Comment: Glad that the first issue has been fixed, if you could mark this answer as correct that would be great. This new issue seems like it may not be parsing the resource correctly. I can't really say more without any more details. You may want to consider raising a new question.

Comment: I solved the problem.thank all of you for your help.it is 3 days i am involved with this errors now some body who i don't know helped me.thank you aloooooooooooooooooot